# Let A be a measurable set in R. Let B be all of it's densed points. is B necessarily open?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set. Define $B$:

$$B =\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{m([x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon]\bigcap A)}{2\epsilon} = 1\right\}$$

Is $B$ necessarily open?

I couldn't find a counterexample, but I also couldn't prove. does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a set $A$ that is *closed* that has *positive measure*, but *empty interior*.

Being closed prevents $A$ from having positive density at points in its complment, i.e. $B\subset A$.

Being of positive measure gives a non-empty subset $B$ of points with density $1$. Recall [Lebesgue's density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem) that says that $A\setminus B$ has measure zero. Therefore $A\cap B= B\neq \emptyset$.

Having $A$ empty interior gives that $B$ has empty interior too, and therefore it is not open.

The classical construction of such sets is [imitating Cantor's ternary set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).

Comment: Quick note: Instead of the Cantor construction, you could also just note that $M=(0,1)\setminus \Bbb{Q}$ has positive measure. By regularity, there is a compact set $K\subset M$ of positive measure. As $K$ contains no rational, it has empty interior.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, that shows the counterexample exists, although we don't get to see how to construct it. The construction gets hidden in the proof of the regularity of Lebesgue's measure.